# Resizing dynamic array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have some code that is producing unexpected results.  Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int **nums;
int size;

void A(int** arr)
{
        int **resize;
        resize = new int*[size*2];

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                resize[i] = new int(*arr[i]);

        cout << endl;
        arr = resize;
        size *= 2;
        delete[] resize;

}

int main()
{
        size = 10;
        nums = new int*[size];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                nums[i] = new int(i);

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                cout << *nums[i] << endl;

        A(nums);

        cout << endl;
        for(int i = (size / 2); i < size; i++)
                nums[i] = new int(i);

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                cout << *nums[i] << endl;

}
```

The function A(int** arr) works fine as far as I can tell and actually resizes the array.  However, in the last for loop in main(), when the array is printing, the first two elements of the array are not 0 and 1 like it is supposed to be.  Here is the result I am getting:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

16331248
16331712
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
```

Those first two ints after the space are different each time the program is executed.  After some debugging I found out that the first two elements print correctly until the iterator i=13 in the second to last for loop in main().  Then the first two elements in the array take on some large numbers.  I am not sure why this is happening and I have been working on this for a couple of hours now :(  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A()` is not modifying `nums` to point at the new array.  Even if it were, it is deleting the new array, so `nums` would end up pointing at invalid memory.  You need to declare the `arr` parameter as a reference, and delete the old array instead of the new array:

```
void A(int** &arr)
{
    int **resize;
    resize = new int*[size*2];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         resize[i] = new int(*arr[i]);

    cout << endl;
    delete[] arr;
    arr = resize;
    size *= 2;
}
```

For what you are attempting, I think you have too much indirection.  Try removing a level:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int *nums;
int size;

void A(int* &arr)
{
    int *resize;
    resize = new int[size*2];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        resize[i] = arr[i];

    cout << endl;
    delete[] arr;
    arr = resize;
    size *= 2;
}

int main()
{
    size = 10;
    nums = new int[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         nums[i] = i;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << nums[i] << endl;

    A(nums);

    cout << endl;
    for(int i = (size / 2); i < size; i++)
        nums[i] = i;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << nums[i] << endl;

    delete[] nums;
}
```

Since you are using C++, you should be using a `std::vector` instead of a raw array, then you can eliminate `A()` altogether:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> nums;

int main()
{
    nums.resize(10);
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
         nums[i] = i;

    for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
        cout << nums[i] << endl;

    nums.resize(nums.size()*2);

    cout << endl << endl;

    for(int i = (nums.size() / 2); i < nums.size(); i++)
        nums[i] = i;

    for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
        cout << nums[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your function, `A`, does not resize anything. It prints a newline character to standard output, it multiplies the global `size` variable by 2, and then it leaks some memory. That's it.

Now, because it multiplies `size` by 2 (going from 10, to 20), you run into a problem, here:

```
for(int i = (size / 2); i < size; i++)
    nums[i] = new int(i);
```

Here, you are trying to access elements 10 through 19 of the array which `nums` points to. But the array which `nums` points to only has 10 elements (numbered 0 through 9), so your code has undefined behavior.